# SQL User permission restore

Tags: sql-server

I restore SQL Database from SQL server 200 to SQL Server 2012 on different devices. I restore the users but when I try to login to the database with the User accounts, it tells me invalid user id or password. The users does not have access to the database anymore even as they exist in the database.

Comment: Did you create the `LOGIN` objects on the new instance? Did you create those `LOGIN`'s with the same SID as the `USER` objects in your database or `ALTER` the `USER` to use the new `LOGIN`?

Comment: Also, to get the true authentication error consult your SQL Server's log. It will most certainly tell you why the authentication is failing.

Comment: I have all users both in Database and Windows security. I can login to the Database from SQL authentication but not in MS Access.